# DNS record parsing: how to differentiate between name and TTL?

Tags: parsing, dns

I'm working on a DNS zone file parser but am confused about the different valid formats that are confusing e.g. for an A record

```
domain.com. IN A 192.168.0.10

@ IN A 192.168.0.10

   IN A 192.168.0.10

abc IN A 192.168.0.10

abc.domain.com. IN A 192.168.0.10
```

This much makes sense and I might figure out a parsing logic for it, but when TTL comes in, I'm not sure how to differentiate record name from TTL.

10 A 192.168.0.111 ;here 10 could be TTL or record name

10 could act as TTL if record is a short form of (@ 10 A 192.168.0.10)
or it could act as record name if actual record is (10 IN A 192.168.0.10)

Can someone clear how to differentiate between TTL and record name.

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034)

> Following the owner, we list the TTL, type, and class of the RR.  Class
> and type use the mnemonics defined above, and TTL is an integer before
> the type field.  In order to avoid ambiguity in parsing, type and class
> mnemonics are disjoint, TTLs are integers, and the type mnemonic is
> always last. The IN class and TTL values are often omitted from examples
> in the interests of clarity.

Which basically means that if it is an integer it is a TTL. according to [RFC 1912](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt) (label = hostname)

> Allowable characters in a label for a host name are only ASCII
> letters, digits, and the `-' character.  Labels may not be all
> numbers, but may have a leading digit

There are some DNS implementations that do allow integer hostnames (bind) however, this does cause problems with other interactions with other systems when it is implemented.

So in your example above, 10 could only be a TTL.

Comment: That's very close to what I wanted to ask, but again I'm currently dealing with a dns record in MSDNS that starts with a number and number is actually hostname and my parser is going nuts on how to consider it as a hostname and not a TTL as both are optional. like for 10 A 192.168.0.111

Answer (score -1):

The DNS zone file format is defined in [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) section 5. The answer to your specific question here is in paragraph 5.1.

Comment: This is barely a link only answer, and doesn't do anything to actually answer the question

Comment: Intentionally so, on my part. Someone who has not read the RFC should not try to parse zone file format, and the answer is spelled out in plain language in the RFC. If you disagree with me, feel free to cut-n-paste the appropriate paragraph from the RFC to an answer here.

Comment: This simply strikes me as a very low quality answer. Particularly due to the fact that the main source of information for zone files is in [RFC 1034](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1034). -  [RFC 1035](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035) has a brief description of implementation details, where as 1034 explains the grammar and syntax

Comment: It wasn't an exact answer that I was looking for but did point to the exact RFC section that I'm currently reading and hoping to make sense out of it. So far i'm still confused about a record that starts with a number and number could be TTL or hostname.